# terminal refresh lags ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

```
$TERM = 'xterm'
```

using ubuntu 11.10.

When I type commands into my terminal, sometimes my input cursor just hangs and no output is visible on my terminal screen. I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> a couple of times, and all of the output gets shown simultaneously to the terminal. I'm using zsh with .oh-my-zsh right now, but I had this same problem when I was using bash, with no real customization done. The thing is, I'm not even sure where to even begin to try to look to fix this problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. Also see this question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/110860/lines-disappearing-intermittently-from-both-terminal-and-emacs But I have not found any solution yet.

Comment: If this is a bug you should report it as one at the appropriate place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably a NVidia card with newest graphic drivers.

Here is a workaround to solve this problem/bug:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/89606/gnome-terminal-doesnt-refresh